# Certain icon for the index in React with Material UI template

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use `if` because I want to add an icon for each `ListItem` but React doesn't let me do so, how should I do it? Should I change something? Thanks in advance.

```
   <List>
      {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
        <ListItem button key={text}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={text} />
        </ListItem>
      ))}
   </List>
```

I tried to use this but it didn't work:

```
<ListItemIcon>
   {index === 0 <InboxIcon/>}
   {index === 1 <MailIcon/>}
   {index === 2 <DeleteForeverOutlinedIcon />}
   {index === 3 <DeleteTwoToneIcon />}
</ListItemIcon>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&&` is missing in your code.
You should write something like

```js
<ListItemIcon>
   {index === 0 && <InboxIcon/>}
   {index === 1 && <MailIcon/>}
   {index === 2 && <DeleteForeverOutlinedIcon />}
   {index === 3 && <DeleteTwoToneIcon />}
</ListItemIcon>
```

Comment: How do we add respective links to each icon?